# Best way to do authorization in webforms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, authorization

Every bit of research on this topic is showing how to do this tasks with MVC, my project is MVP webforms based.  I have the authentication done, but is there a pattern or strategy to best do authorization?

Such as checking for hotlinking on specific pages against a user's role, or hiding ASP controls given a role.

Currently I'm doing things like:

```
if(user.Roles.Contains("Admin")){
     lnkAdmin.Visibility = true; 
}
```

And I don't think that's very clean or maintainable, is there a better way to do these things?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Web Forms way of making specific controls available only to certain roles is to use a [LoginView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview(v=vs.110).aspx) control. Example from the documentation:

```
 <asp:LoginView id="LoginView1" runat="server">
     <AnonymousTemplate>
         Please log in for personalized information.
     </AnonymousTemplate>
     <LoggedInTemplate>
         Thanks for logging in 
         <asp:LoginName id="LoginName1" runat="Server"></asp:LoginName>.
     </LoggedInTemplate>
     <RoleGroups>
         <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Admin">
             <ContentTemplate>
                 <asp:LoginName id="LoginName2" runat="Server" />, you are logged in as an administrator.
             </ContentTemplate>
         </asp:RoleGroup>
     </RoleGroups>
 </asp:LoginView>
```

To prevent users not in certain roles from accessing pages, you can use the [location](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871) elements in your web.config file. Again, another example from the documentation:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms" >
            <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPNETAUTH" protection="None" path="/" timeout="20" >
            </forms>
        </authentication>
<!-- This section denies access to all files in this application except for those that you have not explicitly specified by using another setting. -->
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" /> 
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
<!-- This section gives the unauthenticated user access to the Default1.aspx page only. It is located in the same folder as this configuration file. -->
        <location path="default1.aspx">
        <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
        </system.web>
        </location>
<!-- This section gives the unauthenticated user access to all of the files that are stored in the Subdir1 folder.  -->
        <location path="subdir1">
        <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
        </system.web>
        </location>
</configuration>
```

Similarly, it can be [role based](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config).

```
<location path="AdminFolder">
    <system.web>   
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Admin"/> //Allows users in Admin role    
            <deny users="*"/> // deny everyone else
        </authorization>    
    </system.web>
</location>    
<location path="CustomerFolder">
    <system.web>    
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Admin, Customers"/> //Allow users in Admin and Customers roles    
            <deny users="*"/> // Deny rest of all
        </authorization>    
     </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Does loginview control have a way to prevent hotlinking?  Like typing in a URL to a place a role doesn't have access to?  And how does LoginView know what role the current user have?  I didn't see how that's set in the documentation.

Comment: @Adola No, LoginView doesn't prevent people from accessing pages they're not supposed to. LoginView can access the Roles the user has if you've set it up properly. Look at the documentation I linked to.

Comment: @Adola I've updated the answer to show how to prevent users from accessing pages based on their roles.