# Restrict URL to specific database username ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, mysql, .net

I am making a website tool isch with ASP.NET Framework, that lets a user/customer preview their website.

I have a simple database that gathers a `SESSION["username"]`  and creates a with the source to the customer project file.

But if I have multiple users how am I supposed to prevent users from accessing each other's files using the URL? like if the directory for the customer projects is ? `"~/Customer/SESSION["username"]/Default.aspx` and user1 enters user2 in the directory instead. I will post some content of the page here to make it easier to understand.

Directory of my project

[image: Directory of my project]

In the Default.aspx page I direct everyone that is not the user "admin". And inside the Default.aspx i have an IFrame that looks like this `<iframe id="contentPanel1" runat="server" />` and it gets its src attribute from my Default.aspx.cs that looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;


namespace MyFeedbackWebsite
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            

            if (Session["username"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/login");
            }

            if ((string)Session["username"] == "admin")
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/admin");
            }

            this.contentPanel1.Attributes["src"] = "https://localhost:44350/Customer/"  + Session["username"].ToString();
        }
    }


}
```

In my Admin.aspx.cs I check if the username = admin and if the user is logged in:

```
using System;

namespace MyFeedbackWebsite
{
    public partial class admin : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((string)Session["username"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Login");
            }

            if ((string)Session["username"] != "admin")
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Default");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in the `/Customer/` Directory I want the customers project to be located. But as I mentioned, if the directory is `/Customer/user1/Default.aspx`I want the user1 value to match the current session. Thanks beforehand!

Best regards Max

Comment: You use authorization

Comment: How? Where do I authorize? On the Server or on the actuall website?

Comment: From wherever you serve the page that needs to be restricted.

Comment: So basically I want to restrict all pages depending on the username. The only exception is the user admin that will have access to all the pages. Where can I put in authorization code? Page_Load? somewhere else? web.config?

Comment: You'll have to share a lot more information about the system you're building for anyone to tell. I'm guessing you're using ASP.NET but it's not described. How are people authenticating on your website? Please take some time to search the internet for how to add authorization to the system you're building and then share the code of what you've tried.

Comment: I updated the post with the code ive tried with. But if user1 enters etc examplewebsite.com/Customer/user2/ they get to user2's code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### A few observations

Now, I don't know the background of this project you're working on, but it seems you are relatively new to some of the concepts, so I'll just list a few things for you to think about:

- If this is a new project I would highly recommend you to stop and instead look at ASP.NET Core or similar. .NET Framework is slowly being replaced by .NET Core, so a new project based on .NET Framework (such as ASP.NET Web Forms) will quickly become outdated (if it isn't already from the start).
- If this is just a spare time/personal little project, all good (except for above point) - playing around with it is a good way to learn. If it's a commercial or otherwise serious project, however, I would recommend you to read up on security best practices in web applications. Restricting access to a page using a construct like `Session["username"] != "admin"` is bad business and very error prone. [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237869/best-way-to-do-authorization-in-webforms) for an example of configuring which users or roles can access which pages.

#### The problem in question

It's still a little unclear to me what part of your code handles/is run when accessing `/Customer/user1/Default.aspx`. But I would recommend you, that instead of having the username be part of the URL, you are getting the username from the session in the backend instead, and then serving the proper page matching that username:

1. User accesses the URL `/Customer/Default.aspx`
2. Backend verifies that user is logged in. If not, user is redirected to login page
3. Backend gets the `username` from the session and returns the page `<username>/Default.aspx` (note: this is not a URL, but a file path or something similar  that points to the page you are serving - the user never sees this)

Now, the user will not be able to see another user's page because `/Customer/user1/Default.aspx` **is not** a valid URL - `/Customer/Default.aspx` is.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response, I did try to setup this page with ASP.NET core in the beginning but I made the entire project in a console application, I researched a bit and some people were saying that .NET core main purpose is for console applications only. So I started using .NET Framework. I want learn as much as possible and test new things. Should I start a .NET Core project instead?

Comment: @MaxK123 You must have misunderstood what you've read then. Microsoft is moving development away from .NET Framework and over to .NET Core instead. So yes, I definitely would recommend you starting with ASP.NET Core instead (not a console application, but ASP). You can look up "ASP.NET Core Identity" for guides on typical authentication and authorization.